# E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Ive been trying to work with the authentication feature on Firebase (password authentication). For some reason I keep getting the error mentioned in the title.

The create FirebaseUser method is called when a signup button is clicked. On printing the texts from the textviews to the logcat, I see that the texts are being retrieved but for some reason the "task" is not successful and always prints "User creation not successful" to the Log cat

The code is as follows:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Constants
    public static final String CHAT_PREFS = "ChatPrefs";
    public static final String DISPLAY_NAME_KEY = "username";

    // TODO: Add member variables here:
    // UI references.
    private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
    private AutoCompleteTextView mUsernameView;
    private EditText mPasswordView;
    private EditText mConfirmPasswordView;

    // Firebase instance variables
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.register_email);
        mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_password);
        mConfirmPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_confirm_password);
        mUsernameView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.register_username);

        // Keyboard sign in action
        mConfirmPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (id == R.integer.register_form_finished || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                    attemptRegistration();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        // TODO: Get hold of an instance of FirebaseAuth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    }

    // Executed when Sign Up button is pressed.
    public void signUp(View v) {
        attemptRegistration();
    }

    private void attemptRegistration() {

        // Reset errors displayed in the form.
        mEmailView.setError(null);
        mPasswordView.setError(null);

        // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
        String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
        String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

        boolean cancel = false;
        View focusView = null;

        // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password) || !isPasswordValid(password)) {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
            focusView = mPasswordView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        // Check for a valid email address.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = mEmailView;
            cancel = true;
        } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
            mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
            focusView = mEmailView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        if (cancel) {
            // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
            // form field with an error.
            focusView.requestFocus();
        } else {
            // TODO: Call create FirebaseUser() here
            createFirebaseUser();

        }
    }

    private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
        // You can add more checking logic here.
        return email.contains("@");
    }

    private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
        //TODO: Add own logic to check for a valid password (minimum 6 characters)
        String confirmPassword = mConfirmPasswordView.getText().toString();
        return confirmPassword.equals(password) && password.length()>4;
    }

    // TODO: Create a Firebase user
    public void createFirebaseUser(){

        String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
        String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();
        Log.d("Flashchat",email+password);
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                Log.d("Flashchat","User Created: "+task.isSuccessful());
                if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.d("Flashchat","User creation not successful");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The errors appears as follows in the logcat:

> 2020-06-06 18:12:26.528 2326-2326/com.vinkumar.flashchatnewfirebase
>   D/Flashchat: vin@gmail.comtest123 2020-06-06 18:12:26.541
>   2326-2391/com.vinkumar.flashchatnewfirebase E/DynamiteModule: Failed
>   to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor"
>   on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.vinkumar.flashchatnewfirebase-eMd6uDG6jTaXwKuy0N-UVw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.vinkumar.flashchatnewfirebase-eMd6uDG6jTaXwKuy0N-UVw==/lib/x86,
>   /system/lib, /vendor/lib]] 2020-06-06 18:12:26.541
>   2326-2391/com.vinkumar.flashchatnewfirebase E/DynamiteModule: Failed
>   to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor"
>   on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.vinkumar.flashchatnewfirebase-eMd6uDG6jTaXwKuy0N-UVw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.vinkumar.flashchatnewfirebase-eMd6uDG6jTaXwKuy0N-UVw==/lib/x86,
>   /system/lib, /vendor/lib]] 2020-06-06 18:12:27.628
>   2326-2326/com.vinkumar.flashchatnewfirebase D/Flashchat: User Created:
>   false 2020-06-06 18:12:27.629
>   2326-2326/com.vinkumar.flashchatnewfirebase D/Flashchat: User creation
>   not successful

Comment: Make sure your Firebase dependencies are all up to date.

Comment: Try to use the latest version of [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).